# After populate form and formset it only save last row

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Here is my updated view which include main form and formset, about main form it populate and save well, the problem is in formset side

```
def GrnCreate(request, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get('pk')
    grn_no = GrnModel.objects.filter(company_grn = request.user.first_name).order_by('-id')[:1]
    form_lpo = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrderModel, pk = pk)
    lpo_line_item = form_lpo.purchaseorder_lineitem_set.all()
    currencies = CurrencyModel.objects.all().filter(company_currency  = request.user.first_name)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = GrnForm(request.GET or None, instance=form_lpo)
        formset = Grn_LineItemFormset(request.GET or None, queryset=PurchaseOrder_LineItem.objects.none(), instance=form_lpo)
        
        
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = Grn_LineItemFormset(request.POST)
        form = GrnForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            grnmodel= GrnModel.objects.create(vendor_name=form.data["vendor_name"],
                    grn_number=form.data["grn_number"],
                    lpo_number=form.data["lpo_number"],
                    vat=form.data["vat"],
                    address = form.data["address"],
                    date =form.data["date"],
                    descriptions=form.data["descriptions"],
                    currency = form.data["currency"],
                    )
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                type_of_service = form.data["type_of_service"]
                item = form.data["item"]
                quantity = form.data["quantity"]
                rate = form.data["rate"]
                amount = form.data["amount"]
                if type_of_service and item and quantity and rate and amount:
                    Grn_LineItem(vendor_name=grnmodel,
                        type_of_service=type_of_service,
                        item=item,
                        quantity=quantity,
                        rate=rate,
                        amount=amount).save()
            grnmodel.save()
            return redirect('purchase_order_list')  
        #else:
        #    return redirect('grn_create')
    context = {
        "formset": formset,
        "form": form,
        "grn_no":grn_no,
        "form_lpo":form_lpo,
        "lpo_line_item":lpo_line_item,
        "currencies":currencies
    }
    return render(request, 'inventory/grn_create.html', context)
```

Here is my model

```
class GrnModel(models.Model):
    grn_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lpo_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vat = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(max_length=50)
    descriptions = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vendor_name)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'grnmodel'

    
class Grn_LineItem(models.Model):
    vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(GrnModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_of_service = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    item = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=1)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vendor_name)
    class Meta:
        db_table="grn_lineitem"
```

Here is my template which polulate data but save only last row

```
               <tbody>
                    {% for lpo_line_item in lpo_line_item %}
                        <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}">
                            <td><input name="type_of_service" class="form-control input" value="{{ lpo_line_item.type_of_service }}"></td>
                            <td><input name="item" class="form-control input" value="{{ lpo_line_item.item }}"></td>
                            <td><input name="quantity" class="form-control input quantity_qty_rec" id="qty_rec" value="{{lpo_line_item.quantity}}"></td>
                            <td><input name="rate" class="form-control input rate" value="{{ lpo_line_item.rate }}"></td>
                            <td><input name="amount" class="input grn_amount form-control formset-field" id="grn_amount" value="{{lpo_line_item.amount}}"></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        {% endfor %}                   
                        </tbody>           
                </table>
                {{ formset.management_form }}
```

it only save the main form and last row formset

Thank you for your help

some code added for more explanation and easy to understand

Comment: Is grnmodel your main model ?

Comment: `grnmodel` has a pk when you save all your formset ? Can we see form and formset declaration and all code view ?

Comment: my question updated for more clarification Arif and Lucas